# Is there a term for the opposite of anthology?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you define "anthology" as multiple works of one or more authors in a single volume, then what do you call a single work that is published in multiple volumes?

"Lord of the Rings" is a similar case to this situation, but not really apt, because each volume of the 3-volume work has a unique title that it was published under.

Specifically, I have "The Decline and Fall of the Roman Empire" (Gibbon) in 2 editions: the first is a 2-volume edition, and the second is a 6-volume edition. The individual volumes are basically titled: "Volume 1", "Volume 2", and so on.

The reason I ask is that I'm putting together a desktop/web app to classify and organize my home library, and I have terms for the other common concepts, aside from "anthology":

> "series" -- open-ended list of related titles by the same author(s)
> sharing a story arc
>
> "set" -- close-ended and named collection of works (a.k.a "The Great
> Books of the Western World")

I've looked and searched pretty widely, but I can't find a term for a single work in several volumes. The most common alternative I've seen is "multi-volume set", but that doesn't quite cut the mustard.

The closest thing I've been able to find is the [triple-decker format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-volume_novel) from the Victorian era when novels were often published in 3 parts.

Comment: A work? A book?

Comment: Why, exactly, does *multi-volume* (or *multi-part*) fail to "cut the mustard"? It seems quite accurately descriptive to me.

Comment: _Partwork_ has this meaning but is really magazine-specific.

Comment: TL;DR. **Serial** (or **serialised** if  it's a novel).

Comment: If a collection of articles is an anthology, you are not looking for the "opposite". You are looking for publications where an author has republished his articles. Originally published in X and republished in A, B and C. However, if you are referring to ONE work which includes more than one volume, what's wrong with two-volume, three-volume or trilogy, or multi-volume. You can see that the comments range from suggestions for articles to books. Which is it?? You need to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was pretty clear that I was referring to books, not articles. I could use "multi-volume work" or "a work in n volumes", but I was looking for a single-word term.